# autocomplete search field for blackberry

Tags: search, blackberry, user-interface, autocomplete

I want to implement the an auto complete feature in an app am currently developing. I would have used the Blackberry native auto-complete field but I want the auto complete list to be gotten from a web server. This feature is being implemented in the search screen of google maps for blackberry.

Please can u give ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried to implement this with the native auto-complete field?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried implementing it with the native auto-complete field but it gets its list from the BasicFilteredList class which is a fixed list. I want the list to be gotten dynamically from a directory list online. Something like ajax but using java now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try but I don't see any issue to do that. 
You need to add listener for the EditField - `getEditField` will help you.
After getting list of suggestions, you pack them to `BasicFilteredList` and set it to `AutoCompleteField` with `setFilteredList`.

You should think also about implementation of case when network is not reachable.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but the problem with that approach is that I want the auto-suggestion to be triggered by the 'keydown event' or 'on pressing a key'. I am thinking of overriding the default keypressed method of the screen class.

Comment: You will be notified about text changes if you added listener to EditField.

Comment: Okay. I will try to implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Great example from http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/04/how-to-use-autocompletefield/

After getting your data back from the web server, store the searchable data as `String[]`.

Then you just need the following code to make your AutoCompleteField work:

```
BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();

//my query to sqlite database, yours could just be parsed from your webserver or whatever
String[] list = db.getSearchSuggestions(totalCount); 

filterList.addDataSet(1, list, "list", BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
final AutoCompleteField autoComplete = new AutoCompleteField(filterList);
```